# How to get all Windows Form Elements in a list

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a windows form application.

Windows form consist of several elements. I can reach each of them by their name. 
(ex: textbox1.Text)

Can I get all of form element in a collection?

Comment: `this.Controls` (assuming `this` is your form class)

Comment: **this.Controls.Find()**

Comment: @gunr2171 for example I want to get only textboxes. how can I get with this.Controls? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the method below to traverse a tree and get all of the child controls (at all depths) below any control.

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control root)
{
    var stack = new Stack<Control>();
    stack.Push(root);

    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        foreach (Control child in next.Controls)
            stack.Push(child);

        yield return next;
    }
}
```

You can then pass in the form as the root to get all of the controls in that form in a single sequence.  Use `ToList` if you want them all in a `List` instead.

If you want to filter out only the controls of a particular type, use `OfType`:

```
var textboxes = GetAllControls(someForm).OfTYpe<Textbox>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.Controls` (or more formally: [`Control.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx))

To get all `TextBox` controls, use this:

```
this.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(x => x is TextBox);
```

This will only get top level items. If you need to go deeper (cue inception), you need to do some recursion.

Comment: That won't be all of the controls, just all of the top level controls.

Comment: @Servy, true, but when are you going to have a textbox inside a textbox? Though a valid argument is a textbox inside a panel or other container.

Comment: Yes, and such containers are *very* common in winform programming.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.Controls in the code behind file and should give you a list of all the controls.

Comment: That won't be all of the controls, just all of the top level controls.

Comment: You are right your answer is better was about to write a recursive method to do what you just did.

Comment: You could, if you wanted.  It would perform quite a bit more poorly though, and wouldn't be as flexible.  There really isn't much in the way of advantages.